# Align image and text in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 main-container">
      <h1>Welcome</h1>
      <hr>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-2">
                 <img class="pull-left" src="http://placehold.it/32x32"/>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-4">
                <h3>Capture Everything.</h3>
                <p>Save all your data, data are significant and crucial.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-2">2</div>
              <div class="col-sm-4">2</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-2">3</div>
              <div class="col-sm-4">3</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">Column 2</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is the working link:
http://jsbin.com/kojorike/1/edit

How can i create a something like below with `image in left column and text in right column`?

http://postimg.org/image/x24ukc74j/

Answer (score 0):

In bootstrap each  `class="row"` consists out of **12 colums.**
meaning you have to use them.

example:

```
<div class="row">
    <p class="col-md-8">text text text</p>
    <img src="/image.jpg" class="col-md-4" />
</div>
```

Note. you can use `class="col-md-offset-5"` to add a spacing between the previous element.

Comment: I did not understand the class="col-md-offset-5" part. can you explain a bit more.

Comment: Without the "offset" your elements will be set next to eachother by their defined margin. if you add some offset you can move elements further from eachother seprately.